# How do I solve this equation for x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x=(1-\frac{1}{x})^\frac{1}{2}+(x-\frac{1}{x})^\frac{1}{2}$
How do I solve for x?

Comment: Hint. Square both sides. You'll still have a square root on the right, but you can isolate it and square again. Be careful to check all the roots you find since you might introduce extra ones when you square.

Answer (score 1):

We see that
\begin{align}
x&=(1-\tfrac1x)^\frac12+(x-\tfrac1x)^\frac12\\
x^2&=1-\frac1x+x-\frac1x+2(1-\tfrac1x)^\frac12(x-\tfrac1x)^\frac12\\
x^2-x+\frac2x-1&=2(1-\tfrac1x)^\frac12(x-\tfrac1x)^\frac12\\
\left(x^2-x+\frac2x-1\right)^2&=4(1-\tfrac1x)(x-\tfrac1x)\\
-3+\frac4{x^2}-\frac4x+6x-x^2-2x^3+x^4&=-4+\frac4{x^2}-\frac4x+4x\\
0&=x^4-2x^3-x^2+2x+1\\
0&=(1+x-x^2)^2\\
0&=x^2-x-1\\
\end{align}
And so we see that $x=\phi$ or $x=1-\phi$, the golden ratio. We need to check our solutions however, since squaring can create extra ones; and we see, that only $x=\phi$ satisfies the original equation.

Comment: you have to check the Solutions since you have squared the equation

Comment: I did, but I made a mistake for $x=1-\phi$. It's fixed now.